# Cosa significa : a lui fanno capo?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, nouns

Ciao a tutti,

Ho alcuni problemi nell'utilizzo e comprensione di alcune frasi e parole in questo brano:

> A lui fanno capo 500 entità commerciali e 21 istituzioni finanziarie. Valgono almeno 50 milioni ciascuna. Si tratta della più vasta rete di ricchezze di un capo di Stato Usa. Ecco come insidiano l’equità del ruolo.

- Cosa vuol dire *fanno capo* in inglese ?
- Quando è meglio *ciascuna* di *ognuno* ?
- Come si usa *si tratta*?

Comment: Mi sono preso la libertà di riscrivere la domanda per correggere la grammatica e renderla più facilmente leggibile. Purtoppo la versione originale era molto sgrammaticata (ma non disperare, siamo tutti qui per imparare). Potrebbe essere d'aiuto se chiarissi il tuo livello di italiano, visto che alcune delle domande sono molto vaghe.

Comment: @Denis grazie per il comment,  non sono sicuro se hai modificato il testo della mia domanda,  magari solo indicare gli errori mi aiutava di più

Comment: "Modalità d'uso?" Cosa vuoi dire?

Comment: @Farzad64 Francamente, gli errori erano parecchi e una completa discussione trascenderebbe la lunghezza di un commento. Si trattava principalmente di errori di ortografia, accordi tra aggettivo e nome, e mancanza di preposizioni.

Comment: @Charo È un termine leggermente "burocratese" per indicare come dev'essere utilizzata una particolare cosa. Per un espressione affine pensa a *istruzioni per l'uso*.

Comment: @Denis ti ringrazio, cmq se mi solo indici delle mie errore nelle mie prossime domande,  sarò molto grato,  non un lungo commento ma solo una indicazione

Comment: @Charro - la richiesta di traduzioni è on-topic su questo sito?

Comment: @Farzad64 Per esempio, il tuo commento avrebbe dovuto dire "se mi indichi solo i miei errori" e "un'indicazione": il primo perché il verbo *indicare* fa *indichi* alla seconda persona singolare, non vuole la preposizione *di*, il plurale di *errore* è *errori* ed è una parola maschile. Il secondo perché l'articolo *una* elide la *a* davanti a vocale.

Comment: "Fanno capo" puo' venire tradotto in inglese come "report to". "A lui fanno capo X", "X fanno capo a lui" -> "X report to him"

Answer (score 7):

***[Fare capo](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-capo)*** è un'espressione idiomatica che ha i seguenti significati:

> - 1. ***dipendere, essere soggetti***: questa filiale fa capo alla sede di Milano
> - 2. ***considerare qcn. come referente per informazioni e sim***.
> - 3. ***terminare, sboccare***: la via fa capo in una grande piazza

(De Mauro)

Nella tua frase, il significato è quello descritto al   punto 1. "Da lui dipendono 500 unità commerciali e 21 istituzioni finanziarie."

Answer (score 4):

Ecco una mia approssimativa traduzione in inglese:

> There are 500 commercial entities and 21 financial institutions ultimately connected to him. They are worth at least 50 million dollars each. It is the most expansive network of wealth for a US head of state. Here is how they compromise the impartiality of the role.

Per rispondere alle tue domande in ordine:

- *Fare capo a* non ha, a mio parere, un'esatta traduzione in inglese. In questo caso *X fa capo ad Y* significa che X (un'azienda, partito o altro soggetto giuridico) è (possibilmente in modo molto indiretto) controllata da Y.
- *Ciascuno* ed *ognuno* sono essenzialmente sinonimi (ma nota che in questo caso viene usata la forma declinata al femminile). *Ciascuno* mi suona più idiomatica in questo contesto (quando si parla di elementi di un elenco) ma avrei accettato *ognuno* senza battere ciglio.
- *Si tratta di* (lit. *we are talking about*) in questo caso è usato per indicare l'argomento della frase. Spesso può essere rimpiazzato dal solo verbo essere (*È*) senza grossi cambiamenti di significato.