# Qual è il significato di "fare capo" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *L'affaire Moro* di Leonardo Sciascia, ho trovato questa frase con l'espressione "fare capo" di cui non riesco a cogliere del tutto bene il senso:

> Ma un’evidenza concatenata ad altre evidenze: e tutte che **fanno capo al** concetto di clandestinità delle Brigate rosse.

Ho letto le risposte a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/7660), ma non mi sembra sia lo stesso significato. Ho letto anche le definizioni di "fare capo" nei dizionari Treccani, De Mauro e Hoepli, ma continuo a non capire. Potreste spiegarmi qual è il senso di questa espressione nella frase sopra citata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Fare capo](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fare-capo)***:

> - ***dipendere, essere soggetti***: questa filiale fa capo alla sede di Milano
> - considerare qcn. come referente per informazioni e sim.
> - terminare, sboccare: la via fa capo in una grande piazza

De Mauro

Tra i vari significati, quello che viene usato nella frase è il primo inteso in senso figurato.

- evidenze che fanno capo (dipendono da/hanno come riferimento) il concetto di clandestinità....